# concatenate dictionaries over a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries (with some data fetched from an API) assume:

```
alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':35}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':87}..]
```

There are multiple dictionaries which are repeated in `alist`. But only one of key has a different values out of repeated dictionaries.So, the query is:

What's the easiest way to combine those dictionaries by keeping separate values in a list?

like:

```
alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':[3, 35, 87]}...]
```

**Update** - I have a list which specifies me the repeated keys like:

```
repeated_keys = ['c',...]
```

Comment: The result will be easier to manipulate later if you make them all the same type: `[{'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 35, 87]}`. If this is not acceptable, maybe you are using the wrong data type and need to stop for a moment and consider why you are receiving this sort of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
result = [alist[0].copy()]
result[0]['c'] = [d['c'] for d in alist]
```

Note that there is little point in making this a list again; you combined everything into *one* dictionary, after all:

```
result = dict(alist[0], c=[d['c'] for d in alist])
```

If you have *multiple* repeated keys, you have two options:

- Loop and get each key out:

  ```
  result = alist[0].copy()
  for key in repeated:
      result[key] = [d[key] for d in alist]
  ```
- Make **all** keys lists, that way you don't have to keep consulting your list of repeated keys:

  ```
  result = {}
  for key in alist[0]:
      result[key] = [d[key] for d in alist]
  ```

The latter option is alternatively implemented by iterating over `alist` just once:

```
result = {}
for d in alist:
    for key, value in d.items():
        result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Comment: This skips right over the problem that very likely underlies the situation: why is the data shaped that way to begin with? I smell the an X-Y problem.

Comment: @zxq9: why not post that as a comment on the question then?

Comment: I did. But when a >400k user gives a one-liner code response (that is *completely accurate*, of course) to the Y part of the question the tendency is to completely forget there may be an X -- so I thought it was worth mentioning here.

Comment: @zxq9: I don't think the situation is all that strange; use any generic API with a specific enough query and stuff can easily repeat in the output. That's not the generic API's fault.

Comment: I defer to your experience, then. I've learned a lot about the quirks of CPython over the years from you, actually (so thanks!). Maybe I'm just thinking too strictly about the shape of data because of the influence of other languages I've been using more lately.

Answer (score 2):

Use `defaultdict` (**it is faster** ) and generate dictionary from it- you can also easily convert that dictionary into list.You can modify `j in i.keys()` to filter keys.

```
from  collections import defaultdict as df

d=df(list)

alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':35}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':87}]

for i in alist:
    for j in i.keys():
        d[j].append(i[j])

print dict(d.items())
```

Output-

```
{'a': [1, 1, 1], 'c': [3, 35, 87], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}
```

If you want to get rid of repeated element from that  use `dict-comprehension` and `set`-

```
>>>{k:list(set(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
>>>{'a': [1], 'c': [35, 3, 87], 'b': [2]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, seems, in this case I will need to make set(non repeated)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
con_dict = defaultdict(list)
alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':35}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':87}]

for curr_dict in alist:
    for k, v in curr_dict.iteritems():
        con_dict[k].append(v)

con_dict = dict(con_dict)
```

We create a default dict of type list and then iterate over the items and append them in the right key.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get your result.You have to test if you want to create a list if items has different values or keep it as is.

`repeated_keys` is used to store repeated keys and count how many times they are repeated.

```
alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':35}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':87}]

z = {}
repeated_keys = {}
for dict in alist:
    for key in dict:
        if z.has_key(key):
            if isinstance(z[key], list):
                if not dict[key] in z[key]:
                    repeated_keys[key] +=1
                    z[key].append(dict[key])
            else:
                if z[key] != dict[key]:
                    repeated_keys[key] = 1
                    z[key] = [z[key], dict[key]]

        else:
            z[key] = dict[key]

print 'dict: ',z
print 'Repeated keys: ', repeated_keys
```

output:

```
dict:  {'a': [1, 3], 'c': [3, 35, 87], 'b': 2}
Repeated keys:  {'c'}
```

if:

```
alist = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':35}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':87}, {'a':3,'b':2}]
```

output should be:

```
dict:  {'a': [1, 3], 'c': [3, 35, 87], 'b': 2}
Repeated keys:  {'a': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Comment: @Laxmikant If you need more explanation just comment.I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for collections.Counter: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @MKesper the wanted result is `z` not `repeated_keys`.